# Node.JS: Reusing sockets?

Tags: node.js

I tries to execute this script:

```
require('net').createServer().listen('/tmp/test');
```

First time script runs successfully, but on the second start node.js throwing error: **Error: listen EADDRINUSE**

Is there any way to reuse sockets (unix and tcp too)?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your script/listener/server from the first call is still running. You have to kill the script/process that is listening in order to use the same port again.

Comment: This error occurs even when node is no longer running, as long as the Unix domain socket is not removed by hand

Answer (score 0):

The 'right' way (according to the Node.js docs) is to close the server with `server.close()`, this removes the creates domain socket from the file system.

So if you run the server again you don't have the 'EADDRINUSE' error because it recreates|removes a new domain socket each time.

On windows (with named pipes) we don't have this problem, once the server process is closed the OS automatically removes the created named pipe